# Creating a batch script to open a file that prompts for username and password?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a local website running in my work place and there are a few links that require admin rights in order for them to be opened. I am wondering if there is a way to create a batch file to do this?

The end users have admin accounts, but I would like that when the link is clicked it prompts for a username and password. Is this possible?

I had one temporary solution which was:
    START %windir%\system32\runas.exe /user:EMEA\ACCOUNTNAME-%USERNAME% "mmc               %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"

This would open AD for example and would always run as EMEA\ACCOUNTNAME-%USERNAME%. This also prompted for a password which was perfect. It only has one flaw -  It's restricted to ACCOUNTNAME! New members of the team have different account names so there is no way for it to recognize the password since the account name is incorrect.

e.g My account name is "ACCOUNTNAME", so I click the link and it opens a DOS window and says "Enter the password for EMEA\ACCOUNTNAME-%MyUserName%". This is fine for me, but what about the guy who has a different AccountName?

Things to note: The site is only basic and doesn't feature a log in option, so there is no way to solve this in that way.

Comment: why didn't you use `/user:%userdomain%\%username%`. Do you expect the batch file to served from the website or is the batch file local and runs an http request?

Comment: The batch file is served from the website. So whatever user clicks the link to open AD in this case will be prompted to run or save. Usually run is selected, and then the user is asked to enter a username, and enter a password based on whatever username they've entered. See the below answer I posted! :)

Answer (score 2):

After some thought, I came up with the answer.

Below is the answer for opening Active Directory:

```
@echo off
set var=Please Enter the Account name you use here:
set /p USERID= %var%
START %windir%\system32\runas.exe /user:%USERID% "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
```

So basically, take whatever the input is and store it in "var". Then "set /p" takes user input, so we set that variable equal to var. (USERID =%var%)

Start whatever application you want (In this case AD) with whatever the user has input as their account name!

Answer (score 0):

```
:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo off
cls
:init
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "batchpath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchname=%%~nk
set "vbsgetprivileges=%temp%\oegetpriv_%batchname%.vbs"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:checkprivileges
net file 1>nul 2>nul
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotprivileges ) else ( goto getprivileges )
:getprivileges
if '%1'=='elev' (echo elev & shift /1 & goto gotprivileges)
echo.
echo set uac = createobject^("shell.application"^) > "%vbsgetprivileges%"
echo args = "elev " >> "%vbsgetprivileges%"
echo for each strarg in wscript.arguments >> "%vbsgetprivileges%"
echo args = args ^& strarg ^& " "  >> "%vbsgetprivileges%"
echo next >> "%vbsgetprivileges%"
echo uac.shellexecute "!batchpath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsgetprivileges%"
"%systemroot%\system32\wscript.exe" "%vbsgetprivileges%" %*
exit /b
:gotprivileges
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='elev' (del "%vbsgetprivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)
:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo off
set var=Please Enter the Account name you use here:
set /p USERID= %var%
%windir%\system32\runas.exe /user:%USERID% "cmd /c mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
ping 127.0.0.1
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
exit /b n
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for contributing! I think your answer would benefit however if you provided some context with your script. There could be other people finding this post wanting to understand better how it is used and what it does.